# Create Shared Member Variable between instances (static)

Tags: python

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067/1767754 I know

1) Static members  in Python are not the same Static members in C++

2) Only newly created instances will have the latest Value synced Value of the static Variable

```
class Test:
    var = 3
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = Test()
print "a " +  str(a.var) #output: 3
Test.var = 5
b = Test()
print "b " + str(b.var) #output: 5
print "a " + str(a.var) #output: 3 not synced with static member
```

So what is a usual way of sharing member variables between class instances? What about creating a Global Class that holds the shared Data? like that:

```
class Globals:
    var = 3
class Test:
    def setVar(self, var):
        Globals.var = var

test = Test()
test.setVar(3)
print Globals.var
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that, it always outputs the class' value. Also, static variables behave exactly like in C++, but don't forget that adding properties to objects can happen dynamically and lookup will first look in the instance and then in the class...

Comment: However, I got 5 in the last output..

Comment: Sorry i've created bullshit, i am quickly checking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only newly created instances will have the latest Value synced Value of the static Variable

Not true. Perhaps you are confusing the behavior of:

```
class Test:
    var = 3
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = Test()
print "a " +  str(a.var)
Test.var = 5
b = Test()
print "b " + str(b.var)
print "a " + str(a.var)
```

Output:

```
a 3
b 5
a 5
```

with the behavior of

```
class Test:
    var = 3
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = Test()
print "a " +  str(a.var)
a.var = 2   # Making var a member of the instance a
Test.var = 5
b = Test()
print "b " + str(b.var)
print "a " + str(a.var)
```

```
a 3
b 5
a 2
```

In the second case, `var` is not only a static member of `T`, it is also a member of instance `a`.